# Как отцентрировать кнопку

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Еле как отцентрировал кнопку через Grid, используя тег button, но если хочу сделать через тег a? Кнопка расплывается по экрану, пробовал через inline-block тоже не получается, только если двигать margin'ом вправо, что сразу делает эластичность кнопки никакой. Вроде задача несложная, но просто до меня не доходит, как сделать это красиво.

```css
/* ======SERVISES====== */

.servises {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.servises__item {
  width: 33.333333%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.servises__title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.servises__icon {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.servises__subtitle {
  color: #787878;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.servises__text {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #787878;
  font-weight: 100;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.servises__btn {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 65px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5e407c, #4a50a8);
  background-size: 200%;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.servises__btn:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #5e407c, #4a50a8);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="servises__title">KREA.</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="servises">
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-1.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Consultacy</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-2.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Mentorship</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-3.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Incubatory</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="servises__btn" href="#">GET IN TOUCH</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы как-то неправильно понимаете грид. Грид -- это сетка, в которую надо помещать какое-то содержимое. Кнопка это контент, а не грид. То есть надо делать как-то так:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 100vh;
}
.button {
    place-self: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: indigo;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button">get in touch</a>
</div>
```

Но тогда не понятно, зачем вам нужен грид. Грид обычно нужен для взаимного расположения нескольких блоков контента, а у вас одна кнопка. Есть несколько способов выровнять блок по центру, например такой:

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: indigo;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="button">get in touch</a>
</div>
```

Но в современной веб-вёрстке элементы не располагают просто так. Кнопка начинается и заканчивается в строго определённых местах, имеет строго определённую высоту, отступы. Такую вёрстку вы много раз видели в журналах, на афишах (посмотрите что такое [модульная сетка](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) в графическом дизайне). Сетку закладывает в макет графический дизайнер, задача верстальщика просто перенести сетку в css. Если в макете грида нет, то использовать grid в css мало смысла (для выравнивания элементов подойдёт flex, он гораздо проще).

Comment: Отличный ответ, согласен, я намудрил и совсем забыл про наследование. Да, делаю по макету. Хотел изначально все сделать через flex, но у меня проблема с восприятием кода какая-то, в плане того, что я не всегда понимаю где разместить ту же кнопку или картинку, чтобы дать родителю flex-свойство.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* ======SERVISES====== */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.servises {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.servises__title {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  padding-top: 150px;
  font-size: 55px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}

.servises__icon {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.servises__subtitle {
  color: #787878;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

.servises__text {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #787878;
  font-weight: 100;
  max-width: 450px;
}

.servises__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 25px 65px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5e407c, #4a50a8);
  background-size: 200%;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
}

.servises__btn:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #5e407c, #4a50a8);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="servises__title">KREA.</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="servises">
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-1.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Consultacy</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-2.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Mentorship</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="servises__item">
      <img class="servises__icon" src="img/services-3.png" alt="">
      <h4 class="servises__subtitle">Incubatory</h4>
      <div class="servises__text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam itaque quibusdam non consequuntur? Commodi, illum! Nostrum expedita laboriosam officia, eligendi libero quos, eos ad aperiam mollitia quia enim velit. Deleniti.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="servises__btn" href="#">GET IN TOUCH</a>
```